# Why can't I get an excel file from an S3 bucket into my Lambda code due to an unsupported operation?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am creating an AWS Lambda function which involves getting an existing Excel (.xlsx) file from an S3 bucket. The Excel file is then read and transformed into a DataFrame using the Pandas library. I have been able to successfully complete the same process for a CSV file in the same S3 bucket, but I have received an 'UnsupportedOperation' error when attempting this with the .xlsx file.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import boto3
import logging

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
acc_tech_s3_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='trend-exemptions-inputs', Key='aws-acc-tech-service.xlsx')

acc_tech_s3_object_body = acc_tech_s3_object['Body']

logger.info("acc_tech: %s", str(acc_tech_s3_object_body))
logger.info("acc_tech type: %s", type(acc_tech_s3_object_body))

df_account = pd.read_excel(acc_tech_s3_object_body, sheet_name="aws-acc-tech-service")
...
```

To which I receive the following error:

```
Test Event Name
Test

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "seek",
  "errorType": "UnsupportedOperation",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 32, in <module>\n    df_account = pd.read_excel(acc_tech_s3_object_body, sheet_name=\"aws-acc-tech-service\")\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/excel/_base.py\", line 478, in read_excel\n    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/excel/_base.py\", line 1496, in __init__\n    ext = inspect_excel_format(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pandas/io/excel/_base.py\", line 1375, in inspect_excel_format\n    stream.seek(0)\n"
  ]
}
```

...and the following logs:

```
[INFO]  2023-06-09T14:12:35.512Z        acc_tech: <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f88e65ba1f0>
[INFO]  2023-06-09T14:12:35.512Z        acc_tech type: <class 'botocore.response.StreamingBody'>
```

I appreciate that it appears to be a 'seek' operation within the Pandas library, but why does this error occur only for my Excel file? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: At least on possible fix: download the excel file fully before trying to parse / load it.

Comment: It looks like Pandas doesn't like the response body from Boto3, or is trying to do something with that response body that is not supported. I suggest including the Amazon provided SDK for Pandas Lambda layer https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ which will allow you to read directly from S3 using Pandas without having to write any Boto3 code.

Comment: The short answer is a xslx file is a zip file, which requires seeking, unlike other formats, to read the file contents since some necessary metadata is stored at the end of zip files.  If the file is small enough to fit in memory, you can wrap the file in a buffer using something like `acc_tech_s3_object_body = io.BytesIO(acc_tech_s3_object_body.read())` before passing it to Pandas

Comment: @AnonCoward thank you for explaining the reason for this error. Unfortunately, after using `acc_tech_s3_object_body = io.BytesIO(acc_tech_s3_object.read())` I still get an error: `"errorMessage": "'dict' object has no attribute 'read'",`. I've tried a few different adjustments but ultimately hit against this error

Comment: Did you try using the sample code I provided?

Comment: @AnonCoward thanks - I tried this again and it worked. Initially, I was combining the statements like so: `acc_tech_s3_object_body = io.BytesIO(acc_tech_s3_object['Body'].read())` and this wasn't working (I'm not clear on why that might be). Making them separate statements has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I now have the answer to my question thanks to the suggestion from AnonCoward in the comments.

I needed to utilise the BytesIO class of the io library.

Here is my working code solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import boto3
import logging

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
acc_tech_s3_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='trend-exemptions-inputs', Key='aws-acc-tech-service.xlsx')

acc_tech_s3_object_body = acc_tech_s3_object['Body']

acc_tech_s3_object_body = io.BytesIO(acc_tech_s3_object.read())

df_account = pd.read_excel(acc_tech_s3_object_body, sheet_name="aws-acc-tech-service")
...
```